# maximum and minimum value of binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, minimum

I don't understand how this isn't working:

```
Node* BST::Minimum(Node *curr) {

    if (curr->left != NULL) {
        Minimum(curr->left);
    }

    return curr;

}
```

I mean I already did insert fine, and printpostorder, inorderr, preorder fine.

Am I doing something silly? 
This just prints the root node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `Minimum` and throw its return value away. You want `return Minimum(curr->left);`.

By the way, I strongly recommend doing this iteratively rather than recursively, like this:

```
  Node* node = curr;
  while (node->left != NULL)
      node = node->left;
  return node;
```

Comment: hmm I changed it to:  if (curr->left != NULL) {
        return(Minimum(curr->left));
    } but when it executes this line it just says run failed.

Comment: What is the "it" that says "run failed"? Is this some kind of submission system that validates your output?

Comment: Using cygwin and g++ and netbeans. Just says run failed when it gets to that line. I think that means there is a segmentation fault.

Comment: You may be overflowing the stack if your tree has a loop or is huge. It's also possible you never set `left` to `NULL` and so you go off into outer space.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not though. Because insert works just fine, I can print the tree and it works fine. Just the minimum and maximum giving me issues which is odd.  http://pastebin.com/1fEbd51T Anything that sticks out to you?

Comment: Your `Minimum`/`Maximum` functions are missing a `return curr;` at the end (if `left`/`right` *is* `NULL`). Also, your `free` calls don't do anything because you set the pointers to `NULL` *before* you call `free`, you need to do it after.

Comment: thanks, you cleared up all the confusion :3
i have to wait 1 minute b4 it lets me put your solution as the solution.